# Empty Cart and Add the Selected Product/Item

Tags: cart, ce-1.9.0.1

I want that the all product/item on the cart will be empty and add the current selected product/item on the cart. Could the be possible?

Comment: What is the "current selected product"? What's the context?

Comment: The current product has the product id only.

Answer (score 1):

`Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->removeAllItems();` should do the trick for removing all items. How you add the "current product" depends on the context.